# Does the use of storyteller variables with secondary indexes reduce performance in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I would like to make a system to report the number of people who went to a course during an event with a counter variable. The primary key would be the event id and the secondary key would be the name of the stage.
Take, for example, an area where there are tech companies.

```
CREATE TABLE event (
    event_id text,
    stand text,
    nb counter,
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, stand)
)
```

```
INSERT INTO event(event_id, stand, nb) VALUES (2, "appel", 0);
INSERT INTO event(event_id, stand, nb) VALUES (2, "google", 0);
INSERT INTO event(event_id, stand, nb) VALUES (2, "amazon", 0);
```

My problem is that in the cassandra documentation it is advised to put as few indexes as possible on the counter tables. The best is to create a single table with two indexes or to create a table for each type of stande (which will not require more command to recover the information)

```
CREATE TABLE stand_name (
    event_id text,
    nb counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
)
```

```
INSERT INTO google(event_id, nb) VALUES (2, "appel", 0);
INSERT INTO amazon(event_id, nb) VALUES (2, "google", 0);
INSERT INTO apple(event_id, nb) VALUES (2, "amazon", 0);
```

Comment: I've got a feeling that I've misunderstood your question so feel free to provide additional context and I'd be happy to update my answer. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez I made a modification with an example to make the questioning clearer

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to index. And FWIW, you've got `event_id` as CQL `text` but inserting an integer. Also, you cannot do an `INSERT` for counter tables, just `UPDATE`. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez The inserts just help to explain my idea. Then there will be an update that adds 1 every time someone comes to a booth. The question is whether it is more optimal to make one table per booth or one table that contains all the counts of all the booths.

Comment: In fact my question is : 
can the use of partition key reduce the performance when writing a counter variable? If I use different tables, I will have to get in each table.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I'm confused by your question and don't quite understand how indexing comes into play.

With counter tables, you can only have:

- the columns which form the primary key, and
- the counter column itself

To retrieve the counter value, you must provide the primary key:

```
SELECT counter_col FROM counter_tbl WHERE pk = ?
```

There is no benefit in creating secondary indexes on the table because there really isn't anything to index -- there are no other columns stored in a counter table other than the counter itself. Cheers!